# Can not update newly created column

Tags: sql-server, transactions, alter

Hello i am altering an `SQL` table in which i want to add a new column `A` , and , set its default value based on the value of another column `B` .How could i do that ?

I have tried  so far:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='T' AND COLUMN_NAME='B')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE T ADD B bit default 0;
UPDATE T
SET B = A
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'B'.
```

**P.S** : I want to do the two statements atomically ( alter table  and update the newly created column)

I was expecting this to be a problem with `Intellisense` in `MSSQL` but to be able to run commands in sequential order.

**Update**

I have also tried to separate into two statements,still to no avail:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
              WHERE TABLE_NAME='T' AND COLUMN_NAME='B')
ALTER TABLE T ADD B bit default NULL;

UPDATE T
SET B = A
WHERE B = NULL
END
```

Comment: Why not just make it a computed column?

Comment: I do not know what are the implications to do it as computed column.This is a full fledged column and i will update it in the future.I just need a way to create it and initialize it .

Answer (score 3):

Before a batch is run, it is parsed by the data engine and any syntax errors and invalid object references are raised. Unfortunately, some DDL statements aren't counted for latter statements. Firstly, if we `CREATE` and try to `INSERT` into a table, this works fine:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (A bit);

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (A)
VALUES(1),(0),(1),(1),(0);
```

On the other hand, if we then try to (in a separate batch) `ALTER` the table and then `UPDATE` the value of said column, the batch will fail (as in your example):

```sql
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD B bit default 0;

UPDATE YourTable
SET B = A
```

One method is to separate the statements into separate batches, however, you won't be able to wrap both statements in your `IF` then. Therefore, in this scenario, it would be better to have the statement be parsed in the batch later, by executing it with `sys.sp_executesql`:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='T' AND COLUMN_NAME='B')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE T ADD B bit default 0;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'UPDATE T SET B = A;';
END
```

Comment: What does this `sys.sp_executesql` do ? . Does it basically do it at runtime ? Something like Ignoring the structure at compile time or something ? Does it execute dynamic queries ? I have also tried with 2 statements to no avail

Comment: It does "what it says on the tin", @BercoviciAdrian . It executes sql. [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The `UPDATE` statement is still in the same scope and batch though in that update, @BercoviciAdrian , so it's still going to fail. Adding a line break between 2 statements changing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need the "GO" command between alter and update.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD B bit default 0;
GO
UPDATE YourTable
SET B = A
```

or

```
 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='T' AND COLUMN_NAME='B')
    BEGIN
      ALTER TABLE T ADD B bit default 0;
      EXEC ('UPDATE product SET B = 1')
END

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='T' AND COLUMN_NAME='C')
    BEGIN
      ALTER TABLE T ADD C varchar(20) default null;
      EXEC ('UPDATE product SET C = ''test''')
END
```